# Undelete dialog shows number of delete votes left

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-undelete

When I try to undelete a question, the dialog box systematically shows me how many *delete* votes I have left:

[image: 0 votes remaining]

But I actually have undelete votes left, and I am able to undelete the question:

[image: Undeleted question]

In these screenshots, I have zero delete votes left, and the dialog displays zero undelete votes left. But I still had undelete votes left and was able to undelete the question. This morning I tried again, and it always showed me how many delete votes I had left (I tested).

Is it possibly related to [this earlier bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19444/negative-number-of-delete-votes-left) that affected the display of delete votes left?

---

This bug is even stranger than I thought. When I vote to delete a post, and it's the last delete vote, the question is deleted. When I click `undelete` on this page, it shows the correct amount of undelete votes left. But as soon as I reload, it reverts to showing the number of *delete* votes left when I click `undelete`!

Comment: I just now confirmed the bug is in the display: it's showing the amount of delete votes remaining, not undelete votes remaining.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug is still around 7 months later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed, will go out in build 3763 on MSE/MSO, and build 2884 on other sites.

This was caused by a cut and paste error in which the deletion vote count was used instead of the undeletion vote count. This only affected display, and did not affect the actual mechanics of undeletion.